# ACR User dialogs - Change busy indicator color?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

How do I change the default color of the activity indicator - Loading Spinner in ACR user dialogs. For the Loading Instance. I tried to make changes in my "style.xml" but it is not working and there is nothing about this in the git hub repo.

***Update :*** [image]

Comment: There is only a mask type for progress dialogs. Black, Clear, Gradient, and None. It behaves slightly different between each platform.  `UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Loading...", null, "OK", true, MaskType.Gradient);` .

Comment: I want to change the color of the android loading indicator. Check my update

Comment: It mean that I can't change that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case , you just need to use the default `ActivityIndicator`  in forms . The property **Color** is available

```
<ActivityIndicator x:Name="dialog" >

  <ActivityIndicator.Color>
          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color" Android="Red"  iOS="Black"></OnPlatform>
   </ActivityIndicator.Color>

</ActivityIndicator>
```

And set the value of `dialog.IsRunning` to display  or hide the dialog .

Comment: Sorry, but I'am talking about the loading indicator displayed by acr user dialogs himself. For example the loading indicator on the image is yellow and I want to change the color of that. Could you check the new image uploaded in my update ?

Comment: I'm afraid that we could not implement it if you do want to use the plugin .

Comment: By the way , why do you have to use the plugin ?

Comment: I use acr user dialog to display a loading indicator when I realize background task. But if I cannot change the default color of the spinner I will probably use the native xamarins forms loading indicator